# mount.nfs: access denied by server

Tags: mount, nfs

I am trying to mount an NFS share from one Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian 10) on another Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian 10) but I keep getting an error.

```
$ sudo mount -vvvv -t nfs 172.20.0.14:/mnt/backup/foo /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Aug 22 13:41:53 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=172.20.0.14,clientaddr=172.20.0.12'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 172.20.0.14:/mnt/backup/foo
```

Although I can mount the exact same NFS share on my laptop (Manjaro Linux) without problems.

In the `/etc/exports` file I have added this line:

```
/mnt/backup/foo      172.20.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

The permissions of `/mnt` on the client:

```
$ ls -lnd /mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 0 0 4,0K Feb 13  2020 /mnt
```

The permission of `/mnt/backup/foo` on the server:

```
$ ls -lnd /mnt/backup/foo
drwx------ 3 1000 100 4,0K Aug 22 13:28 /mnt/backup/foo
```

Comment: if you "tried everything" then it must work! What are the permissions of the directories? `/mnt` is owned by root it would be unusual to mount anything there.

Comment: The permissions of `/mnt` on the client: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K Feb 13  2020 /mnt`. I also tried to create a folder `foo` in `/home/pi` and mount the NFS share there. Same result.

Comment: what's the permissions of `/mnt/backup/foo` on the **server** - since it's the server that is causing permission denied

Comment: It's also unusual to export `/mnt/anything` since `/mnt` is like a general purpose mounting point that is rarely (i.e. never) used for permanent mounts

Comment: The permissions of `/mnt/backup/foo` on the server are: `drwx------ 3 pi users 4,0K Aug 22 13:28 /mnt/backup/foo` (uid: 1000, gid: 100). The user on the client is having the same uid and gid.

Comment: What does the logs on server say, why it denies access?

Comment: I don't see any log messages in `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` or via `journalctl -fl`. So I tried to enable debug messages via `rpcdebug -m nfsd -s all`  but then I get the error `/proc/sys/sunrpc/nfsd_debug: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are the permissions of the folders on the server. All folders needs `chmod +rx`.